# Boosting Values in Elastic search

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I want to set a boosting for values in fields, while searching the following strings in elastic search

Index value

```
id title
1. stack installer
2. stack
3. stack material
4. installer
```

I searching those values using match query, then i got a following result

**Query:**

```
curl -XGET localhost:XXXX/index/type/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"matchpharse":
     {"title":"stack installer"},
     "minimum_should_match":90
}'
```

**Hit Result:**

```
stack installer
installer
stack material
stack
```

But,I Need following order of output

```
stack installer
stack
stack material
installer
```

Answer (score 0):

In boolean should statement , you can give multiple queries of should and boost certain query over other.

```
curl -XGET localhost:XXXX/index/type/_search?pretty -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "title": "installer stack",
            "boost": 3
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "installer",
            "boost": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "stack",
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Its working fine...Incase my input is "stack installer controller".. i can get the result in fixed query,not changing the query frequently..

Comment: If i search **stack over flow** or **stack over flow installer**,@Kumar asking, A single Query to achieve that result. ..How to set Boost value to 'Stack' term..

Comment: For each term whose priority you want to increase , you need to add a different match query for that term alone. Put the rest in the match query. .

Comment: I set a boost property in match query,it will not work